# Using JDBC connector with Gradle (Intellij Project)

Tags: java, gradle, jdbc, build.gradle, mysql-connector

I've been struggling for hours trying to use jdbc connector in my project. Despite reading the official doc, I installed mysql-connector as follows `implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.33'` in the build.gradle but I have this error
`Not a module and no mapping defined: mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar` persisting. I hope someone can help me!

Here is my `build.gradle` :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
    id 'org.gradlex.extra-java-module-info' version '1.0'
}

group 'com.ficobrillance'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'brillance.btf'
    mainClass = 'brillance.btf.HomeApp'
}

javafx {
    version = '19'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/brillance.btf.HomeApp"

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.2.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.2.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/SparseBitSet
    implementation group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'SparseBitSet', version: '1.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.6.1'

    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.33'
}

extraJavaModuleInfo {
    module('commons-math3-3.6.1.jar', 'commons.math3', '3.6.1')
    module('SparseBitSet-1.2.jar', 'SparseBitSet', '1.2')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    forceMerge('log4j-api' )
    launcher {
        name = 'BTF'
    }
    jpackage {
        jpackageHome = '/Users/yassineougnoun/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.7/Contents/Home'
        imageName = "BTF"
        installerName = "BTF-installer"
        appVersion = "1.0.0"
        vendor = "Yass Company"
        skipInstaller = false
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

and my `module-info.java` :

```
module brillance.btf {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires org.apache.poi.poi;
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;
    requires java.sql;

    opens brillance.btf to javafx.fxml;
    exports brillance.btf;
    exports brillance.btf.controller;
    exports brillance.btf.modele;
    opens brillance.btf.controller to javafx.fxml;
}
```

I'm using Gradle 8.1

I've already tried to add the lib manually but I get another error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`